# Contact Form Validation - Change 'Phone' to Optional

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using the Twitter-Bootstrap Agency theme and I need to change the phone validation to optional.

HTML

```
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Your Name *' id='name' required data-validation-required-message='Please enter your name.'>
                                <p class='help-block text-danger'></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <input type='email' class='form-control' placeholder='Your Email *' id='email' required data-validation-required-message='Please enter your email address.'>
                                <p class='help-block text-danger'></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <input type='tel' class='form-control' placeholder='Your Phone' id='phone' data-validation-required-message='Please enter your phone number.'>
                                <p class='help-block text-danger'></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <textarea class='form-control' placeholder='Your Message *' id='message' required data-validation-required-message='Please enter a message.'></textarea>
                                <p class='help-block text-danger'></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='clearfix'></div>
                        <div class='col-lg-12 text-center'>
                            <div id='success'></div>
                            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-xl'>Send Message</button>
                        </div>
```

I tried removing the line:

```
required data-validation-required-message='Please enter your phone number.'
```

But it didn't successfully send a test message. Any help?

Comment: Please provide the full code, where is the "name", it is required for getting or posting data from html form. Just remove "required" and put "name"(like name="phone") in the form and then try to send a test message.

Comment: I've edited my post to show the full contact form. I tried removing 'required' from #phone, but it responded saying I must enter a phone number.

Comment: Are you using javascript?

Comment: I just took a look and it looks like there is a jqBootstrapValidation.js file linked to the template, but it's really long. What specifically might I be looking for in the file?

Comment: I suggest you to use simple html form, remove all javascript and put "required" if field require some data before submit.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it with the current form. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

Go to the file mail/contact_me.php

Comment out line 5 (or which ever you want changed to optional)

Save and open index.html

Remove or comment out the following input items from the contact form:

```
 required

 data-validation-required-message='Please enter a phone number.'
```

Save and upload both files to your server